# Projective closure of an algebraic set and related ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, homogeneous-equation

Polynomials and ideals of $k[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ resp.
$k[X_1, \cdots, X_n, Z]$ are considered, with $k$ an arbitrary field. Only
classical algebraic geometry is considered (no schemes).

Definitions: $f^*$ is the homogenization of $f$ relatively to $Z$; $I^*$ is
the ideal generated by $\{ f^* | f \in I \}$; $V^* = V(I(V)^*)$.

Question 1: Is $\sqrt{(I^*)} = (\sqrt{I})^*$ true ?

Question 2: Is $V(I)^* = V(I^*)$ true if $k$ is algebraically closed ? Or do
only their affine parts ($Z = 1$) agree ?

Question 3: Is there a counter-example of the latter if $k$ is not
algebraically closed (but possibly infinite) ?

I do not necessarily need detailed proofs, but I would like to know if those
claims are correct or not (possibly with some hints or references).

Comment: I found a counterexample for question 3:
$k = \mathbb{Q}$ and $I = (X^3 - Y^2 + 4 \cdot X)$.
Indeed, in $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$, $V(I) = \{ (0, 0), (2, 4), (2, -4) \}$,
which is finite, such that $V(I)^*$ has no extra points at infinity. But
$V(I^*)$ does have an extra point at infinity: $[ 0 : 1 : 0 ]$.